# Ubuntu Thunderbird version is behind the Windows version

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

I have my Thunderbird profile on an external disk so I can use it for my mail on both my Ubuntu laptop and Ubuntu desktop. I had to do some work on a Windows 11 partition, so I opened the Thunderbird profile there.
It seems the Windows 11 version of Thunderbird is 115.x.x, while my Ubuntu versions are 102.x.x. I can't open the Thunderbird profile on Ubuntu any longer.
Is there a way to convert the profile back to the Ubuntu-supported version?

Comment: As of today, the Ubuntu deb is 102.x.x, and the Desktop Team is working to update it. Be patient. It takes time. That's one reason sharing a profile is not recommended.

Comment: " Is there a way to convert the profile back to the Ubuntu-supported version?" that is a problem from the WIndows end not Ubuntu.